# Jquery touchstart - how to stop Copy/Define iPad/iOS

Tags: jquery, ios

I have created a simple Jquery scroll for a div on a page which works perfectly, apart from on iPad, touching the down button for any length of time cause the iPad to ask if I want to Copy or Define.

Is there a way to tell it to not do this? Or is there another way to do this whole scroll thing on iPad/iOS?

Here's the Jquery (also using mousedown for desktops):

```
$('#down').on( "mousedown touchstart", function(){ 
        timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(5)}, 20);
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks for the inspiration guys:

Firstly: `e.preventDefault();` causes a horrible almost vibrating for some reason but from there tried `return false` which works perfectly.

**ANSWER**

```
$('#down').on( "mousedown touchstart", function(){ 
        timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(5)}, 20);
        return false;
    }).bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent default events:

```
$('#down').on( "mousedown touchstart", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(5)}, 20);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchend instead of mouseleave as follow:

```
$('#down').on( "mousedown touchstart", function(){ 
        timeoutId = setInterval(function(){scrollIt(5)}, 20);
    }).bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
```